# How to get a variable in a running python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

If I have two python files: py1 and py2.

```
#py1.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while(1):
        a=1
```

```
#py2.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

My question: How can I get the value 'a' in py2 when py1 is running. (I can't modify py1)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? (Yes, the reason affects the answer.) Debugging?

Comment: there are a variety of ways in which interprocess communication can be done if thats what you are looking for. googling it would be best.

Comment: @Ry- yes, debugging. I'm trying to write a test script for a  program without changing the program. The program defined all their variables in "if __name__ == "__main__":" part and it doesn't provide any APIs to access them. So I'm thinking is it possible to access them in another script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hack, and anti *pythonic*, so I strongly discourage the use of this in any production environment, but alas:

```
import runpy
result = runpy._run_module_as_main("py1.py")

print(result['a'])
```

Comment: If you can modify py1, easy to go is use os env. Store value to Env, ao you can read it inside py2